# FileNotFoundException With FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload files more than one but I am just trying single fileupload for practice but I am getting file not found exception my task is as under.

```
private static void UploadFileToFtp(string source) 
{
    String ftpurl = @"ftp://ftp.yuvarukhisamaj.com/wwwroot/Shtri/";  //“@ftpurl”; // e.g. ftp://serverip/foldername/foldername
    String ftpusername = "yuvarukh";//“@ftpusername”; // e.g. username
    String ftppassword = "CXhV5Rzeu";//“@ftppassword”; // e.g. password      

    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(source);
        string ftpfullpath = ftpurl;
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
        ftp.KeepAlive = true;
        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(source);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Close();
        Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
        ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ftpstream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String sourcefilepath = FileUpload1.FileName;
    UploadFileToFtp(sourcefilepath);
}
```

Error Details is `An Exception of type “System.IO.FileNotFoundException” Occurred in Bshadow.DLL but was not handle in usercode`.
Additional information: could not find file `C:\Programfiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\IDE\dd.jpg`

How can I upload multiple files with fileUploaders Via FTP?

Comment: can you see the file when you paste C:\Programfiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\IDE\dd.jpg to windows explorer?

Comment: @vgSefa, No it is located at " E:\Asp.Net Test\YuvaRK12\YuvaRK12\Shtri\dd.jpg" but it isn't available at C:\Programfiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\IDE\dd.jpg

Comment: @user2741987 Well thats your problem you are tring to load a file that dosent exist at the specified location.

Comment: @dburner, So if i wants to transfer the file to another server than the specified file should have to keep at C:\Programfiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\IDE\dd.jpg is it compulsory?. if i wants to transfer the file from my pc from another source than it can't be uploaded?.

Comment: I tried your code. Works fine. Can you try via breakpoints and pressing F10 to execute line by line to see witch line is problematic?

Comment: @user2741987 No, i'm saying you have to define your `source` variable better. You are probabily using a relative path (like `\dd.jpg`). Try to set the full path to the file like `E:\Asp.Net Test\etc\etc\dd.jpg`

Comment: @dburner, Yes You are right I have did it and make certain changes in my code and now it's works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ad ftpurl address the folder/file.ext to upload

Also you use a simple exception you must handling exactly exception not generally one.

in example your full path for ftp must be :

```
@"ftp://ftp.yuvarukhisamaj.com/wwwroot/Shtri/" + filename + ext;
//ftp://ftp.yuvarukhisamaj.com/wwwroot/Shtri/yourimage.ext;
```

that fix your issue.

it is a common error in ftpclass of net.